# Looping and Lists - BaSe fOO ThE AttAcK

Tags: python

In the war against Skynet, humans are trying to pass messages to each other without the computers realising what's happening.

To do this, they are using a simple code:

They read the words in reverse order They only pay attention to the words in the message that start with an uppercase letter So, something like:

BaSe fOO ThE AttAcK contains the message:

attack the base

However, the computers have captured you and forced you to write a program so they can understand all the human messages (we won't go into what terrible tortures you've undergone). Your program must work as follows:

soMe SuPPLies liKE Ice-cREAm aRe iMPORtant oNly tO THeir cReaTORS. tO DestroY thEm iS pOInTLess.

code: soMe SuPPLies liKE Ice-cREAm aRe iMPORtant oNly tO THeir cReaTORS. tO DestroY thEm iS pOInTLess.

says: destroy their ice-cream supplies ​

Notice that, as well as extracting the message, we make every word lowercase so it's easier to read.

Could you please help me with my code? This is my code so far:

```
output=[]
b=0
d=0
code=input("code: ")
code=code.split()
print(code)
a=len(code)
print(a)
while b<a:
  c=code[b]
  if c.isupper:
    output.append(c)
    b=b+1
  elif c.islower:
    b=b+1
  else:
    b=b+1
print(output)
```

I need the last line to say "BaSe ThE AttAck" eliminating "fOO" and I will be reversing the string in the last step to make sense, but it is not differentiating between a lowercase word and an uppercase word.

Comment: Your code is difficult to read. Try to use meaningful variable names to make it readable. Also it would help if you could show the input and output you get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have rewritten your code.

```
#code=input("code: ")
code = "soMe SuPPLies liKE Ice-cREAm aRe iMPORtant oNly tO THeir cReaTORS. tO DestroY thEm iS pOInTLess"

code=code.split()


output = []
for word in reversed(code):         #iterate over the list in reverse
    if word[0].isupper():           #check if the FIRST letter (word[0]) is uppercase.
        output.append(word.lower()) #append word in lowercase to list.
output = " ".join(output)           #join the elements of the list together in a string seperated by a space " "
print(output)
```

output

```
destroy their ice-cream supplies
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's My answer, Tested on grok learning and green across the board:

```html
    code = input('code: ')
        code=code.split()
        output = []
        for word in reversed(code):         
            if word[0].isupper():           
                output.append(word.lower()) 
        output = " ".join(output)           
        print('says:', output)
```

Comment: How does this code differ from the code in the accepted answer?

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues with your code:

1. `isupper` and `islower` are methods, i.e. you need to call them by writing `()`.
2. `c.isupper()` will check if the entire word is upper-case. However, your problem description says to just consider the first character of each word. Hence, try using `c[0].isupper()`.

Now, after that has been fixed, you're still left with reversing the `output` list (and making each word lowercase) but I suppose you didn't get to that just yet. :-)